# How to remove black bar from the YouTube videos

Tags: jquery, iphone, youtube-javascript-api

The black bar appears in the YouTube video, it looks little odd when the video plays.  Can we remove that black space from the videos? I want to remove that black space and shows the video at desire aspect ratio as the we choose for the player size. For now I am using the stander google YT player API.

Is it make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

[This is what you want -- while you have to customize a bit more; it achieves the functionality you desire](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)

Answer (score 0):

Try the chromeless player.

You can develop your own controls in javascript - completely customized.