# Remove black bars from either side of an embedded YouTube video

Tags: css, video, youtube, html5-video, embedded-video

I've embedded a YouTube Video on [this webpage](http://babykitchen.machinemade.ie/about/).

I want to remove the two black bars that appear when I click play.

See screenshot here:

[image: ugly black side bars]

I searched on Stack Overflow and the closest I found was this, but it didn't help:

[How to remove black bar from the YouTube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364273/how-to-remove-black-bar-from-the-youtube-videos)

So I tried adjusting the video with the following CSS:

```
  html5-video-container {
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      position: absolute;  
    }

    video.video-stream.html5-main-video {
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

At first I tried just adjusting the video, then I tried adjusting the video container element as well, but neither worked.

Can any CSS gurus help me please?

I would like the video to be the same size as the thumbnail that appears before one clicks play.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more of an issue with the YouTube frame than css.

The YouTube frame is as wide as the page, but as tall as the actual video. That means there is going to be *a lot* of extra space, it has to fill it with something!

As long as the YouTube frame is wider than the actual video, there is going to be black space. You need to make the aspect ratio of the YouTube frame match the actual video.

Comment: Looks like no one else is going to provide an answer, so I just wanted to say thanks for your contribution.

Comment: although after setting the aspect ratio the black bars went away, but video is out of the 100vh boundary. Is there any way to force the video to not go deeper than 100vh while aspect ratio is given?